# run linux bash script on adb shell

Tags: android, linux, shell, adb

I'm trying to run linux shell script on adb shell. It's giving errors!
Here is the whole story:

I wrote a simple bash script hello.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello
{
    echo "hello world!"
}

hello
```

running it as ./hello.sh produces the o/p

```
hello world!
```

Now I pushed the file to android device using

```
adb push hello.sh /data/folder_name
```

then ran following command to enter in adb shell

```
adb shell
```

In adb shell fired following commands

```
cd /data/folder_name
chmod 755 hello.sh
sh hello.sh
```

This is what I get on adb shell :

```
# sh hello.sh
sh hello.sh
function: not found
hello world!
hello: not found
#
```

What's happening here!
Or is there some different way to write function for adb shell script

I searched but didn't get proper solution
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about adb, but 'function' is not standard syntax.  It is available in many shells, but the standard way to define a function is:

```
hello() { echo hello world; }
```

Answer (score 0):

When invoked as `sh`, bash enters posix mode and it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.

The reserved word `function` is optional for bash, but I think is unknown to historical versions of `sh`.

Try to invoke the command as

```
bash /tmp/test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to push the script to your phone - simply expand it in the shell itself like so and you save yourself time:

```
adb shell "$hello.sh"
```

Comment: What shell supports that kind of expansion?